# On Yosemite, NSWindowController seems retain its "contentViewController" even when it dealloc

Tags: cocoa, osx-yosemite, retain, nswindowcontroller

On Yosemite,When you create a simple document-base app using Xcode's template,you will get a storyboard which contains a windowController object and a customized NSViewController object and the  former's contentViewController is the Latter(by a triggered segues connection).Then you can write a subclass of NSWindowController and set it as the windowController object's class.

Launch the App and it shows a empty window,close the window,you will find the NSWindowController  object and the window object are all dealloc(by overriding their dealloc methods),but the ViewController object is still alive! And when you set the  NSWindowController.contentViewController as nil in it's dealloc method, the ViewController object is dealloc finally. I think it's a bug of Yosemite.Am I right?

Comment: I think it is a bug. I found that I cannot have any IBOutlets on my content view controller and that need to set self.contentViewController = nil in window controller dealloc.

Comment: same here. viewcontrollers are not get deleted when i change the self.contentViewController to another viewcontroller.